# How can I set a gateway in a local network?

Tags: networking, routing

Homework disclaimer...

So I have computer A whose IP address happens to be `192.168.0.81`. This computer has a web server installed and exposes port 80. So typing `192.168.0.81` in the web browser address bar of any other computer of this local network displays this webpage.

But I also have another computer in this local network: `192.168.0.129` And my task is to configure the two in such a way that `192.168.0.129` will be a NAT gateway for `192.168.0.81`. All packets sent by `192.168.0.81` must go through `192.168.0.129` and `192.168.0.129` must forward all traffic it receives on port 80 to `192.168.0.81`.

Solution attempt. Execute this on server to hopefully make it send its responses through `192.168.0.129`:

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.129
```

Execute this on gateway to hopefully allow it to forward traffic from server to outside world:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Execute this on gateway to hopefully make it forward traffic it receives to server:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.129 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.81:80
```

Yet it doesn't work. Typing `192.168.0.129` in the web browser address bar of another computer in this network (`192.168.0.185`) displays browser error rather than this webpage. What am I doing wrong?

In an effort to somehow find out what's going on I tried logging all packets by issuing on both machines:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
```

These are the results. It seems the server receives packets from the original request maker and tries to send some packets back. I'm seeing entries of this sort:

```
Dec 19 23:23:25 debian kernel: (...) IN= OUT=eth0 MAC=(...) SRC=192.168.0.185 DST=192.168.0.81 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=(blah blah this and subsequent stuff omitted for brevity)
Dec 19 23:23:25 debian kernel: (...) IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.0.81 DST=192.168.0.185 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=(...)
```

However, gateway's logs don't seem to show any relevant traffic.

How to fix this?

Comment: You seem to be mixing what is the destination and source... Better drawing in a sheet of poster  in this cases. The route also does not seem to be needed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Am I? I'm re-reading my Q but can't find such a mistake. Could you point me where I mixed them?

Comment: Kind of late and sleepy here, but in the iptables rule I think it should be tcp -s ....129 (and not -d)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not sure, why? My thinking is that the gateway is supposed to forward packets sent *to* it (hence -d) to the server? With `-s 196.168.0.129` the gateway will only forward to the server the packets it sends on its own. Either way, tried putting -s instead of -d, and now the server doesn't seem to receive any packets when ...185 makes its request :(

Comment: Forwarding only works between different subnets. You are trying to route traffic on the same physical (layer 2) network through a gateway, which won't work (unless the .129 machine works like a bridge with two distinct network interfaces, but then again that's not forwarding really, that's bridging).

Comment: For NATting to work, the .129 system must process both the requests from .185, and the responses from .81. This is because when on .185 the browser makes a request for 192.168.0.129, it will expect the answer to come from .129. But when the .81 sees the redirected request from .185 to .81 and prepares a response for it, it sees .185 is in the same network segment so it will attempt to send the answer directly to .185. This will confuse the .185: "I wasn't talking to you; I was talking to .129!"